# Positioning div in center of window (vertically)

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using this CSS to postion a div horizontally and vertically to the window which works fine until you scroll down the page, then the div remains in the same centred position as if the page hadn't been scrolled.

```
width:600px;
height:300px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin:-150px 0 0 -300px;
z-index:99;
```

Can this be done using CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed

`position: fixed;` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your `position` is `absolute`!

You should try using `position: fixed;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS: **position:fixed;**